# Hilt inject to viewmodel using the same way as to activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm wondering, why my injecting works only in activity:

it works:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var fakeRepo: FakeRepo

}

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class MainModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFakeRepo(fakeRepoImpl: FakeRepoImpl): FakeRepo
}
```

BUT when I'm trying inject this repo to viewModel this way it gives errors:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(MainActivityViewModel::class)
abstract class MainModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFakeRepo(fakeRepoImpl: FakeRepoImpl): FakeRepo
}

interface FakeRepo {
    fun getData(): List<Int>
}
class FakeRepoImpl @Inject constructor(): FakeRepo {
    override fun getData(): List<Int> {
        return listOf(3,5,6)
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(val fakeRepo: FakeRepo) : ViewModel() {

}
```

Why it doesn't work ? I get

> @InstallIn, can only be used with @DefineComponent-annotated classes

Probably I can inject it using provide as singleton but this is not the solution.
Could someone explain why I can inject to activity but to viewmodel not using @Binds ?

Comment: try `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)`

Comment: after change: 'FakeRepo cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.'